# The requested URL /link was not found on this server. Apache & htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter

The root page at / loads fine, but any other link gives me a `The request URL was not found on this server` error.

my htaccess is in the root of the application folder, and contains the following:

`RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]`

Answer (score 0):

a CodeIgniter `.htaccess` might look alike this... the `RewriteBase` is important there.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

</IfModule>
```